# Cut plaster hole, without hole saw, options?

Tags: electrical, lath-and-plaster

I need to cut one 6" hole for a can light into a plaster ceiling and don't want to spend the money on a hole saw. What are my best options?

Comment: lot of dremel bits will work to "cut" drywall. i think they even make a specific drywall bit. You can use the bit in a non-dremel drill, it's just a bit slower. a rat-tail file can also work in a pinch.

Comment: I would really "not" recommend a spiral saw (dremel) for this. Its actually more work and (a lot) more mess compared to a simple hand saw.

Answer (score 7):

Your best option is a jab saw and a steady hand. 
[image: jab saw]

If your question is how to do it while spending no money the answer is substituting the saw blade in a multi-tool or Swiss Army Knife. Failing that, scoring the plaster with a utility or X-acto and carefully breaking it out.

Comment: Draw a circle, punch the saw through and follow the line, should take about a minute , ok for a novice DIY, maybe 3 minutes.

Comment: Note: Most cans come with a template. Note, note: Be aware of the location of your ceiling joists.

Comment: Is a jab saw the same as a drywall saw? Or is a jab saw stronger to punch through the plaster?

Comment: Same thing. You can jab through most plasters, some exotic ones you may need to drill a hole for the saw.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not the cheapest option, it's only $20. A jab saw may be half the price but with this drill bit you will make a precise circular cut. *AND* it's adjustable and allows you to cut anywhere from 1-3/4 to 7-7/8" circular holes. So it gives you a lot of versatility.

This one is on amazon but you can buy it online through the Home Depot website:

[Heavy Duty Circle Cutter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004T7P1)

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

I'm glad you started this thread because I am going to buy one for myself.

Comment: This type of tool should never be used in a hand drill, only in a drill press and only with the work piece securely clamped. This caution will be printed on the package.

Comment: ^^^ this... if you're not experienced, you run the risk of making a mess of the plaster when this cutter catches and twists away while you're atop a ladder. Strongly recommend a jab saw.

Comment: also, if not properly secured, the cutter can fly off. seen it happen.